# Autocompletar un input dependiente de otro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tengo lo siguiente: un formulario con un campos clientes y otro campo aparatos
en la base de datos cada aparato está relacionado a un cliente por medio del la llave primaria de cliente.

lo que necesito:
En este momento ya tengo el auto completado funcionando en el input cliente:

Html:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cliente">Cliente <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <input id="cliente1" class="span12 form-control" type="text" name="cliente1" placeholder="Ingrese Cliente" value=""  />
      <input id="cliente_id" class="span12" type="hidden" name="clientes_id" value="0"  />
 </div>
```

Js:

```
 $("#cliente1").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>os/autoCompleteCliente",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
             $("#clientes_id").val(ui.item.id);


        }
  });
```

ahora, ¿cual es el problema?... explico:

allí arriba ustedes ven otro input hidden de id equivalente a "cliente_id" (este campo se llena cuando selecciono una opción del autocomplete)
lo que quiero es que este campo de aquí abajo del de name=nombreE:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="nombreE">Nombre/Equipo/Marca/Modelo/Nº Serie (Ej. Pc de Juan/Portatil/Sony/SVG31S) </label>
     <input name="nombreE" type="text" class="form-control" id="acnombreE" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre, Tipo, Marca, Modelo o Serie" value="">
     <input id="aparatosid" class="span12" type="hidden" name="aparatosid" value=""  />
</div>
```

Se autocomplete de la misma forma, pero teniendo en cuenta dos cosas:

1. Lo que yo esté escribiendo en el
2. Lo que está en el campo cliente_id

pero no encuentro la manera de enviar esos 2 parametros usando el autocomplete de jquery ya que jquery solo me manda al servidor un solo parámetro llamado term

esta es la función js que uso para autocompletar el campo en cuestión, pero me arroja todos los aparatos que se parezcan a lo que escribo en el campo, por eso necesito filtrar para que solo me me arroje los aparatos relacionados al cliente que seleccioné mas arriba:

```
    $("#acnombreE").autocomplete({            
        source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>os/autoCompleteaparato
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
             $("#aparatosid").val(ui.item.id);
             $("#actipoE").val(ui.item.tipoE);
             $("#acmarcaE").val(ui.item.marcaE);
             $("#acmodeloE").val(ui.item.modeloE);
             $("#acn_serieE").val(ui.item.n_serieE);


        }
  });
```

alguien me puede echar una mano de como puedo autocompletar ese campo y que me muestre sugerencias mientras escribo, usando el campo antes mencionado ('cliente_id') como segundo filtro,

muchas gracias.

Comment: No mezcles el PHP con el HTML o el Javascript. Crea el código Javascript que llame con AJAX a tu PHP. Con los datos (clientes, aparatos y pares cliente-aparato) ya en local, rellena y actualiza los campos conforme sea necesario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente yo batalle con este embrollo hace unos dias y buscando en internet encontre un ejemplo, el cual me sirvio de ayuda.

uso este fichero de JavaScript para estar a la escucha del form en html (El form lo tengo en un div con id cliente:

```
$(function(){
   /* Ponemos evento blur a la escucha sobre id nombre en id cliente. */
   $('#cliente').on('blur','#operador',function(){
      /* Obtenemos el valor del campo */
      var valor = this.value;
      /* Si la longitud del valor es mayor a 2 caracteres.. */
      if(valor.length>=3){

         /* Cambiamos el estado.. */
         $('#estadoOperador').html('Cargando datos del operador desde servidor...');

         /* Hacemos la consulta ajax */
         var consulta = $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'operador.php',
            data:{operador:valor},
            dataType:'JSON'
         });

         /* En caso de que se haya retornado bien.. */
         consulta.done(function(data){
            if(data.error!==undefined){
               $('#estadoOperador').html('Ha ocurrido un error: '+data.error);
               return false;
            } else {
               if(data.idoperador!==undefined){$('#cliente #idoperador').val(data.idoperador);}
               $('#estadoOperador').html('Datos del operador cargados..');
               return true;
            }
         });

         /* Si la consulta ha fallado.. */
         consulta.fail(function(){
            $('#estadoOperador').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servidor.');
            return false;
         });

      } else {
         /* Mostrar error */
         $('#estadoOperador').html('El nombre tener una longitud mayor a 2 caracteres...');
         return false;
      }
   });
});
```

y posteriormente operador.php donde hago la llamada a la base de datos y busqueda en mi base de datos

```
<?php

/* Conectar a una base de datos de MySQL invocando al controlador */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbsistema;host=localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

try {
    $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Falló la conexión: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(!empty($_POST['operador']))
{ 

    $nombre = $_POST['operador'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM operadores WHERE nombre = :nombre";  
    $stmt = $gbd->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":nombre",$nombre);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Verifica si no hay datos en la consulta
    if($arrDatos){
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row) {
      if ($nombre = $row['nombre']) {
        $return = array ('idoperador'=>$row['numero']);
      }      
    }

} else {
        //Esto ocurre si el nombre está vacío solamente
        $arrDatos = array('error'=>'El nombre está vacío');
}
//Imprimir los resultados 
die(json_encode($return));
}
```